# Recursive CTE of Dates Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, netezza

I have the following code that I run on SQL Server - it returns a table of quarterly dates on the last day of the month, starting from a user-defined first date. I need to implement the code in Netezza SQL:

```
                DECLARE @YEAR INT= 2014 /*year of first date*/
                DECLARE @MONTH INT = 6 /*month of first date*/
                DECLARE @DAY INT = 30 /*day of first date*/

  ;WITH      MONTHS (DATES) AS
            (select DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,@day)
            union all
            SELECT cast(DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,dateadd(month,3,dates))+1,0)) as date)
            FROM MONTHS
            WHERE DATES < dateadd(month,12,datefromparts(@year,@month,@day))
            )

    SELECT * FROM MONTHS
```

I am having troubles trying to figure out how to translate this into Netezza SQL. The output of the sample code would look like so:

```
>     DATES
>     2014-06-30
>     2014-09-30
>     2014-12-31
>     2015-03-31
>     2015-06-30
```

Comment: Adding sample output would be helpful

Comment: just edited to add sample output. Thanks for the suggestion @ScottMcG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netezza does not currently support recursive CTEs, so here is an alternative that will hopefully work for your needs.  The use of a CTE here is entirely gratuitous, as a stand in for the variable declaration you use in your MS SQL code.

```
with starting_date(start_date) as
(
   select '2014-06-30'::date
)
select last_day(add_months(date_trunc('month', start_date), idx*3 )) qtr_date
from starting_date
   cross join _v_vector_idx
where qtr_date <= add_months(start_date,12)
-- where idx < 5
order by qtr_date ;

  QTR_DATE
------------
 2014-06-30
 2014-09-30
 2014-12-31
 2015-03-31
 2015-06-30
(5 rows)
```

The commented version of the where clause will be more efficient, but I used the other version to hew more closely to your original.